# Is there a Dart library that will solve systems of linear equations with complex numbers?

Tags: dart, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

A few years ago I wrote a C# library that is able to perform mesh analyses on simple electronic circuits and I'm now trying to port that library to Dart. In order to do so, I need to be able to solve a system of linear equations that involve complex numbers.

In the existing C# library, I used the "Math.NET Numerics" library and could call:

```
Vector<Complex> x = A.Solve(B);
```

where A is a Matrix<Complex> and B is a Vector<Complex>.

Is there a comparable package for Dart that accepts complex numbers? If not, is there a workaround for converting the complex numbers into a more useful format and then back again?

I have looked at a couple of Dart packages, including [data](https://pub.dev/packages/data), [equations](https://pub.dev/packages/equations) and [scidart](https://pub.dev/packages/scidart). All support solving systems of linear equations, but as far as I can tell, none support doing so with complex numbers.